# Best way to fire an event when app loads a page in cordova app singlepage with jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, kinvey, jquery-mobile-pageshow

I'm trying to fire and event at the loading of my app:
When the app starts, I load the #home page BUT if the user is not cached (I use kinvey), the app should change page to the #login.
How can I accomplish that?

I tryied this code at the beginning of myScript.js file, and this is declared at the beginning:

```
$('#home').on( 'pageshow',function(){
    var user = Kinvey.getActiveUser();
    var promise = Kinvey.User.me({
    success: function(response) {
    $.mobile.changePage('#login'); //should change page here
    });
}
```

I would appreciate suggestions on what event to trigger, because there are many in jquerymobile documentation and I don't know which is the more convenient.

Comment: Are you waiting for Cordova(Phonegap) or jQuery Mobile to load?

Comment: I want to perform a check as the app initialize.
I Should wait for jQueryMobile and kinvey init, so I can decide what page to load.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and tell me if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(document).on( 'mobileinit' , function(){ // will fire as soon as jQM is loaded
    var user = Kinvey.getActiveUser();
    var promise = Kinvey.User.me({
    success: function(response) {
    $.mobile.changePage('#login', {transition: 'none'}); //should change page here
    });
}
```

Alternatives might include:

```
$('#home').on( 'pageinit' ,function(){ /*stuff*/ }); //will fire the first time #home is loaded
$('#home').on( 'pagebeforeshow' ,function(){ /*stuff*/ }); //will fire before home is shown (don't do this, it'll check every time)
```

If you're using cordova and have enabled the splash page in config you could try:

```
$(document).on( 'mobileinit' , function(){ // will fire as soon as jQM is loaded
    var user = Kinvey.getActiveUser();
    var promise = Kinvey.User.me({
    success: function(response) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#login', {transition: 'none'}); //should change page here
        if (navigator.splashscreen /* || 1 */ ){ // so it doesn't crash when you're testing on your browser
            navigator.splashscreen.hide(); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but none of the above work.
kinvey takes a while to connect, so I always get a "kinvey is not defined". Now I'm trying to keep trace of the user access via local storage, it should be faster and safer because it doesn't need a connection, and I will only need cordova to load.

Comment: I solved the problem... I made first page #login, in my login function I added on success callback a request to store the username, and a script (onpagecreate, #login) that checks the existance of that value.
Everything, works fine. If I press the backButton on my phone I exit the app, as it should be.
Thank you anyway for your time.